# SyncAdapter onPerformSync calls only for first time

Tags: android, android-syncadapter

I am building a sync adapter for my app where I want to show notification to users after querying for change in the database every 1 hour even if app will be killed.

I have created the sync adapter successfully but the onPermformSync() only called for the first time and shows me the notification then it doesn't get called after particular time interval(1 hour) even if the app remain on the screen(foreground)

**Note: I am using SyncAdapter instead of WorkManager because WorkManager(the latest version) is not working in some of the chines phones like Oppo Real Me 2 Pro, Real Me 1 etc.**

**Edited: This issue is mainly with above mentioned devices like Oppo Real Me 2 Pro and it's working fine in other devices with poll frequency(periodic sync) of 60 seconds**

I have already created StubContentProvider and StubAuthenticator.

Below is my codes

**ConfigurationSyncAdapter**

```
public class ConfigurationSyncAdapter extends AbstractThreadedSyncAdapter {
public ConfigurationSyncAdapter(Context context, boolean autoInitialize) {
    super(context, autoInitialize);
}

@Override
public void onPerformSync(Account account, Bundle bundle, String s, ContentProviderClient contentProviderClient, SyncResult syncResult) {
    Log.e("sync","onPerformSync is called");
    showNotification(getContext(),"The query","let'see");
}

private void showNotification(Context context, String title, String message){
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        // Create the NotificationChannel, but only on API 26+ because
        // the NotificationChannel class is new and not in the support library
        CharSequence name = "RandomName";
        String description = "RandomDescription";
        int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH;
        NotificationChannel channel =
                new NotificationChannel("ID1", name, importance);
        channel.setDescription(description);
        // Add the channel
        NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        if (notificationManager != null) {
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
        }
    }
    // Create the notification
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, "ID1")
            //used notification icon for testing purpose
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(message))
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
            .setVibrate(new long[0]);


    // Show the notification
    NotificationManagerCompat.from(context).notify(1, builder.build());
    Log.e("WorkManager","Notification shown");
  }
}
```

**ConfigurationSyncAdapterService**

```
public class ConfigurationSyncAdapterService extends Service {

private ConfigurationSyncAdapter syncAdapter = null;
private static final Object syncAdapterLock = new Object();

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    synchronized (syncAdapterLock){
        if(syncAdapter == null)
            syncAdapter = new ConfigurationSyncAdapter(getApplicationContext(),true);
    }
}

@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return syncAdapter.getSyncAdapterBinder();
   }
}
```

**SyncAdapterManager**

```
class SyncAdapterManager {

private static final String TAG = SyncAdapterManager.class.getSimpleName();
private final String authority;
private final String type;

private Account account;
private Context context;

SyncAdapterManager(final Context context) {
    this.context = context;

    type = context.getString(R.string.account_type);
    authority = context.getString(R.string.authority);
    account = new Account(context.getString(R.string.app_name), type);
}

@SuppressWarnings ("MissingPermission")
void beginPeriodicSync(final long updateConfigInterval) {
    Log.d(TAG, "beginPeriodicSync() called with: updateConfigInterval = [" +
            updateConfigInterval + "]");
    final AccountManager accountManager = (AccountManager) context
            .getSystemService(ACCOUNT_SERVICE);

    if (!accountManager.addAccountExplicitly(account, null, null)) {
        account = accountManager.getAccountsByType(type)[0];
    }

    setAccountSyncable();

    ContentResolver.addPeriodicSync(account, context.getString(R.string.authority),
            Bundle.EMPTY, updateConfigInterval);


    ContentResolver.setSyncAutomatically(account, authority, true);
}

void syncImmediately() {
    Bundle settingsBundle = new Bundle();
    settingsBundle.putBoolean(ContentResolver.SYNC_EXTRAS_MANUAL, true);
    settingsBundle.putBoolean(ContentResolver.SYNC_EXTRAS_EXPEDITED, true);

    ContentResolver.requestSync(account, authority, settingsBundle);

}

private void setAccountSyncable() {
    if (ContentResolver.getIsSyncable(account, authority) == 0) {
        ContentResolver.setIsSyncable(account, authority, 1);
     }
   }

}
```

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    SyncAdapterManager syncAdapterManager = new SyncAdapterManager(this);
    syncAdapterManager.beginPeriodicSync(60*60);
    Log.e("sync","onCreate of Main Activity");

   }
 }
```

**syncadapter.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<sync-adapter xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:accountType="@string/account_type"
android:allowParallelSyncs="false"
android:contentAuthority="@string/authority"
android:isAlwaysSyncable="true"
android:supportsUploading="false"
android:userVisible="false">

</sync-adapter>
```

**authenticator.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<account-authenticator xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:accountType="@string/account_type"
android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:smallIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.androidians.syncsample">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SYNC_SETTINGS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SYNC_SETTINGS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.AUTHENTICATE_ACCOUNTS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <service android:name=".AuthenticatorService">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.accounts.AccountAuthenticator"/>
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.accounts.AccountAuthenticator"
            android:resource="@xml/authenticator"/>

    </service>

    <provider
        android:authorities="@string/authority"
        android:name=".StubContentProvider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:syncable="true"/>

    <service android:name=".ConfigurationSyncAdapterService"
        android:exported="true"
        android:process=":sync">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.content.SyncAdapter"/>
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.content.SyncAdapter"
            android:resource="@xml/syncadapter" />
    </service>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Have you tried removing this `android:process=":sync"` ? Just to be sure the problem is not connected with the system killing additional processes

Comment: @MatPag I have given a shot to this but it's still the same case

Comment: i am also facing the same issue. did you found any solution.

Comment: Hi, I faced same issue. But when I tried to rebuild the project and re-installed the APK in device It works. Sometimes it shows this behavior. I think you are following this to links the same as me. 
1. https://josiassena.com/building-a-sync-adapter-and-using-it-on-android/
2. https://gist.github.com/JosiasSena/08ce86683e6361f9531ac9032ae0bcec

Try to use code from second link.